# Disabling letter input on Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, calculator

So I have an assignment for a 101 class and I have no idea how to make it work. I have to disable letter input into a calculator, and using an IsNumeric string doesn't work right, any tips? Code is right here:

```
 Private Sub btnDoIt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e _
                          As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDoIt.Click
    Dim strMSG As String = txtFnum.Text & " + " & txtSnum.Text & " = "
    Dim intAns As Integer = CInt(txtFnum.Text) + CInt(txtSnum.Text) 
    lblAnswer.Text = strMSG & intAns.ToString("N0")
    btnAgain.Visible = True : btnDoIt.Visible = False
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to limit it in your click event instead of your Textbox's Keydown event ?

Comment: Hint: Use `onKeyPress` on `TextBox`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MarkHall Because I'm new at this and don't really understand what I'm supposed to do to this? Also, the only code in any of the textboxes makes this button visible, and as far as I can tell, I need a variable to make use of IsNumeric. Feel free to correct me, this is almost first contact for me.

Comment: @unlimit Its a school assignment, and my teacher like small and simple, not sure if that's what he wants

Comment: @user2998518, I guess you will have to ask your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment I am not going to give you any code, just try to explain it and give you some resources to look at. It appears from your comments and question that you are required to use `IsNumeric` in your solution to the problem. There are two ways to handle this, one is to keep the non numeric value from being input into the TextBox in the first place, the second is to allow anything to be put in then use some sort of validation event like your button click to check(validate) the input.  I prefer to keep the non numeric values from being entered into the TextBox in the first place.   Take a look at the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Event expecially the [`KeyPressEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class it contains the [character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that was pressed and also has an property called [`Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will suppress the key that was pressed.  Use `isNumeric` to check the `KeyChar` and set the `Handled` property to True if it isn't a number.

You can easily use the [`IsNumeric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the validation, just check the TextBox's Text property and clear it or pop a messagebox if the IsNumeric method returns false.